# Lucene.net - How do I create a negative query, ie. search for objects NOT containing something

Tags: c#, asp.net, lucene.net, episerver

I'm working on an EPiServer website using a Lucene.net based search engine.

I have a query for finding only pages with a certain pageTypeId. Now I want to do the opposite, I want to only find pages that is NOT a certain pageTypeId. Is that possible?

This is the code for creating a query to search only for pages with pageTypeId 1, 2 or 3:

```
public BooleanClause GetClause()
{
    var booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
    var typeIds = new List<string>();
    typeIds.Add("1");
    typeIds.Add("2");
    typeIds.Add("3");

    foreach (var id in this.typeIds)
    {
        var termQuery = new TermQuery(
            new Term(IndexFieldNames.PageTypeId, id));
        var clause = new BooleanClause(termQuery, 
            BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
        booleanQuery.Add(clause);
    }
    return new BooleanClause(booleanQuery, 
        BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
}
```

I want instead to create a query where I search for pages that have a pageTypeId that is NOT "4".

I tried simply replacing "SHOULD" and "MUST" with "MUST_NOT", but that didn't work.

---

**Thanks to @goalie7960 for replying so quickly.** Here is my revised code for searching for anything except some selected page types. This search includes all documents except those with pageTypeId "1", "2" or "3":

```
public BooleanClause GetClause()  
{
    var booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();  
    booleanQuery.Add(new MatchAllDocsQuery(), 
        BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

    var typeIds = new List<string>();  
    typeIds.Add("1");  
    typeIds.Add("2");  
    typeIds.Add("3");  

    foreach (var typeId in this.typeIds)  
    {
        booleanQuery.Add(new TermQuery(
            new Term(IndexFieldNames.PageTypeId, typeId)), 
            BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT);
    }  
    return new BooleanClause(booleanQuery, 
        BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);  
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming all your docs have a pageTypeId you can try using a MatchAllDocsQuery and then a MUST_NOT to remove all the docs you want to skip.  Something like this would work I think:

```
BooleanQuery subQuery = new BooleanQuery();
subQuery.Add(new MatchAllDocsQuery(), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
subQuery.Add(new TermQuery(new Term(IndexFieldNames.PageTypeId, "4")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT);
return subQuery;
```

Comment: Excellent, MatchAllDocs was what I missed from my query. Thank you!